# Unable to run node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc. Ensure you have installed it with npm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ampersand.js

Unable to run node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc. Ensure you have installed it with npm.
  (in /Users/labuser/Downloads/betfair_nav_demo-master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

I am using Ampersand JS with Rails application.
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem "browserify-rails", '1.2.0'

I have installed 
npm install ampersand -g

npm install browserify --save-dev

npm install underscore --save

My Rails app is working  without browserify-rails gem.

Answer (score 6):

Try running

```
npm install browserify-incremental
```

It is best, however, to save this to a package.json file (so that when you deploy your code, you only have to run *npm install*, as you would *bundle install*).

If you don't have a package.json file, create one by running:

```
npm init
```

in your rails project's root directory.

Once you've done this, or if you already have a package.json file, you can save packages to it by running:

```
npm install --save <package_name>
```

If you have existing node packages installed in this project, npm init will automatically add these to your package.json file. If *npm init* prompts you for something that you're not sure of, or is not applicable to your application, just press enter and tidy up the package.json file afterwards. You should only ever need to run *npm init* once.

Comment: I think he would need to do `npm install browserify-incremental --save-dev`

Comment: @Trip, if he/she's only going to be using browserify in a dev environment (which I guess is the usual use case), he/she could definitely do that. Thanks for your addition. :)