# BrowserifyRails::BrowserifyError with npm and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, npm

I'm trying to run a local application using ruby on rails. At first time to run local server, it complain about nodejs, which was installed sucessfully.
After, the error when local server is about to run:

```
Unable to run node_modules/.bin/browserify. Ensure you have installed it with npm.
```

Npm was installed and browserify with this command:

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Installed with no problems. But when I do this command

```
npm install browserify-incremental
```

It installs but shows this warning:

```
UNMET DEPENDENCY browserify@^12.0.1 browserify
```

I follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816443/unable-to-run-node-modules-bin-browserifyinc-ensure-you-have-installed-it-with) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I followed instruction from [this link](https://blog.skcript.com/setting-up-browserify-and-react-on-rails-ef5bc0f07cda). Just add this configuration in my application.rb file:

```
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = “ — transform reactify — extension=\”.jsx\””
```

After that, `npm init`, followed by `npm install`. I've executed those commands in the root folder of my project.